# composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0" does not working in Laravel 6.2

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I tried to **install composer require "laravelcollective/html":"^5.4.0"** in Laravel 6.2. The composer.json is:

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
```

However, I got error as below:

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.5.0
        - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.5.0
        - laravelcollective/html 5.4.x-dev requires illuminate/view 5.4.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].
```

Is it because the command does not support the newest version of laravel? Because the newest command I found is v5.8. If yes, is there any way I can replace from laravel 6.2 version to the older version?

Comment: It's pretty obvious from the `composer.json` that v5.4 of the given package works with Laravel 5.4 only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the 6.0 version, newest version of laravel has a lot of breaking changes so also take note on their documentation. for install newst version just run composer `require laravelcollective/html`

[read more](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html)

Comment: How to change the version without disturbing the existing project?

Comment: you are currently on laravel 6.2, so it won't harm your current project, what we do is just add new package which is laravelcollective

Answer (score 0):

If you need the last version try just to run

`composer require laravelcollective/html`